# Dask and fbprophet

Tags: python, pandas, dask, facebook-prophet

I'm trying to use `dask` and the `fbprophet` library together and I'm either doing something wrong or having unexpected performance problems.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import datetime as dt
import multiprocessing as mp 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
from fbprophet import Prophet
import time
ncpu = mp.cpu_count()

def parallel_pd(fun, vec, pool = ncpu-1):
    with mp.Pool(pool) as p:
        res = p.map(fun,vec)
    return(res)

def forecast1dd(ts):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    return ts["y"].max()

def forecast1mp(key):
    ts = df[df["key"]==key]
    time.sleep(0.1)
    return ts["y"].max()

def forecast2dd(ts):
    future = pd.DataFrame({"ds":pd.date_range(start=ts["ds"].max()+ dt.timedelta(days=1),
                                                  periods=7, freq="D")})
    key = ts.name
    model = Prophet(yearly_seasonality=True)
    model.fit(ts)
    forecast = model.predict(future)
    future["yhat"] = forecast["yhat"]
    future["key"] =  key
    return future.as_matrix()

def forecast2mp(key):
    ts = df[df["key"]==key]
    future = pd.DataFrame({"ds":pd.date_range(start=ts["ds"].max()+ dt.timedelta(days=1),
                                                  periods=7, freq="D")})
    model = Prophet(yearly_seasonality=True)
    model.fit(ts)
    forecast = model.predict(future)
    future["yhat"] = forecast["yhat"]
    future["key"] =  key
    return future.as_matrix()
```

In one side I have a custom function which runs in about 0.1 s so `forecast1dd` and `forecast1mp` are simulating my function and  for the following dataframe

```
N = 2*365
key_n = 5000
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({"ds":pd.date_range(start="2015-01-01",periods=N, freq="D"),
                   "y":np.random.normal(100,20,N),
                  "key":np.repeat(str(k),N)}) for k in range(key_n)])
keys = df.key.unique()
df = df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=ncpu*2)
```

I obtain (respectively)

```
%%time
grp = ddf.groupby("key").apply(forecast1dd, meta=pd.Series(name="s"))
df1dd = grp.to_frame().compute()
CPU times: user 7.7 s, sys: 400 ms, total: 8.1 s
Wall time: 1min 8s

%%time
res = parallel_pd(forecast1mp,keys)
CPU times: user 820 ms, sys: 360 ms, total: 1.18 s
Wall time: 10min 36s
```

In the first case the cores are not used at 100% but the performances are in line with my real situation. It is easy to check, using a line profiler, that the culprit for slow performance in second case is `ts = df[df["key"]==key]` and things get worst if we have more keys.

So till now I'm happy with `dask`. But whenever I try to use `fbprophet` things change. Here I use fewer `keys` but unlikely the previous case `dask` performance are always worst than `multiprocessing`.

```
N = 2*365
key_n = 200
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({"ds":pd.date_range(start="2015-01-01",periods=N, freq="D"),
                   "y":np.random.normal(100,20,N),
                  "key":np.repeat(str(k),N)}) for k in range(key_n)])

keys = df.key.unique()
df = df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=ncpu*2)

%%time
grp = ddf.groupby("key").apply(forecast2dd, 
meta=pd.Series(name="s")).to_frame().compute()
df2dd = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(a) for a in grp.s.values])
CPU times: user 3min 42s, sys: 15 s, total: 3min 57s
Wall time: 3min 30s

%%time
res = parallel_pd(forecast2mp,keys)
df2mp = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(a) for a in res])
CPU times: user 76 ms, sys: 160 ms, total: 236 ms
Wall time: 39.4 s
```

Now my questions are:

- How can I improve the performance of prophet with dask?
- What should I do to have dask using cores at 100%?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that Prophet is holding the GIL, so when computing `ddf.groupby("key").apply(forecast2dd, meta=pd.Series(name="s")`, only one thread can run Python code at once. Using `multiprocessing` can sidestep this, at the cost of having to copy your data `ncpu` times. This should have similar runtime to your `parallel_pd` function.

```
%%time
with dask.set_options(get=dask.multiprocessing.get):
    grp = ddf.groupby("key").apply(forecast2dd, 
        meta=pd.Series(name="s")).to_frame().compute()

df2dd = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(a) for a in grp.s.values])

CPU times: user 2.47 s, sys: 251 ms, total: 2.72 s
Wall time: 1min 27s
```

You could try asking the Prophet developers if they need to hold the GIL. I suspect that the issue is in PyStan, and that they probably don't need the GIL when the actual Stan solvers are running. There's a Github issue [here](https://github.com/stan-dev/pystan/issues/179)

---

Side note: since your sample `forecast1dd` is a an aggregation, it can be run much more quickly using a `dd.Aggregation`:

```
%%time

def forcast1dd_chunk(ts):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    return ts.max()

def forecast1dd_agg(ts):
    return ts.max()

f1dd = dd.Aggregation("forecast1dd", forcast1dd_chunk, forecast1dd_agg)

grp = ddf.groupby("key")[['y']].agg(f1dd)
x = grp.compute()

CPU times: user 59.5 ms, sys: 5.13 ms, total: 64.7 ms
Wall time: 355 ms
```

Though this doesn't fit your actual problem, which isn't an aggregation.

Comment: Hi Tom, I tried your method and as well `from dask.distributed import Client` and then `client = Client()` and performance are pretty much the same. The problem is that whenever I use `key_n = 5000` with `forecast2dd` I get the following error: `OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '/dev/null'`

Comment: I solved `OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files` firing `ulimit -Sn 10000` from terminal.